# How to implement a dialog for different activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I want to show the same dialog in different activities. I tried to make a `BaseActivitiy`. The Activities extends my BaseActivity. That worked so far, but now I want to update the Activity which shows the dialog when the dialog is closed. Update means in my case to fill a listview with data from a SQLite database.

I also tried to retrieve the classname to use the update method of those activities. But it is not possible to change the update method to static, because of the non-static SQL methods...

Do you have any idea?

Activity:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Dialogs {
        ...
        @Override  
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)  item.getMenuInfo();
            int idx = info.position;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case CONTEXTMENU_ID:
                   showMyDialog(this,DIALOG_ID);
                   break;
            }      
        return true;
       }

       public void update() {
           ...
       }
    }
```

DialogsClass

```
    public class Dialogs extends Activity {
         @Override
         protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
              ...
         }
         ...
         //Called on Dialog-Butten press
         private void ReloadActivity(){
             if(DialogCalledByClass.contains("MyActivity")) {
                 MyActivity.update();// It doesn't worke because non-static....
              }
              else if(DialogCalledByClass.contains("MyActivity2")) {

              }
         }

         public void showMyDialog(Context ctx,int id) {
             showDialog(id);
             DialogCalledByClass =ctx.getClass().toString();
         }
     }
```

That's what I have tried...

Comment: What class name you retrieving? Where UpdateMethod located? Give more details pls and show your code.

Answer (score 1):

For example... Instead of create a BaseActivity you could create your own Dialog:

```
class myDialog extends AlertDialog {
   Activity myActivity;

   public myDialog(Activity myAct){
      myActivity=myAct;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
      ...
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void dismiss(){
      myActivity.update();
   }


   @Override
   public void cancel(){
      myActivity.update();
   }

}
```

I don't know if I've understood your question, but it's an idea. I hope it help you.

Comment: This goes in the right direction. What should I use as parameter if I invoke `myDialog(?)` in the activities?

Comment: You invoke `myDialog(this)` in the activities. But be careful with myActivity's type because if your activities extend of ListActivity you have to change the type.

Comment: Now I changed showMyDialog to `public void showMyDialog(Activity act,int id){ act.update();}` but it doesn't work because `update()` is undefined for the type Activity....

Comment: ok, sorry, I understood that you have an update method in the activities that manage SQLite DB and fill a listView. So, Where is your update method? and What is its code?

Comment: I think your solution it's too complicate. If the method update it's in the dialog class, you could invoke it in the method cancel or dismiss or hide (Override it). You can do `(new myDialog(this)).show()` don't use method `onCreateDialog` in the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Solution. Thanks to you David!! Sry I couldn't vote up because to less reputation...

```
private void ReloadActivity(){
    if(DialogCalledByClass.contains("MyActivity")){
        try {
            Method m = DialogActivity.getClass().getMethod("Update");
            try {
                m.invoke(DialogActivity);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            error.d(TAG, "SecurityException"+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            Log.d(TAG, "NoSuchMethodException"+ e);
        }

    }
    else if(DialogCalledByClass.contains("MyActivity2")){

    }
}




public void showMyDialog(Activity act,int id){
    showDialog(id);

    DialogCalledByClass = act.getClass().toString();
    DialogActivity = act;

}
```