# Android, Java: Share a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dialog, share

I have a dialog with some TextViews and ImageViews inside. Now I want to share this with the Share Intent. Is this possible? Can I share a dialog or convert it first to a bitmap and then share it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But do you want to share image of your dialog??

Comment: Yes exactly, i have a dialog and want to share it like a screenshot of it.

Comment: Yes you have to convert it first to bitmap and after that share it

Comment: You have a link where is explained how to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method.

```
public static Bitmap TakeBitmapFromDialog(View v, int width, int height) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

OR
simply use this.

```
 View v1 = view.getRootView();
 v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
 BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
```

***UPDATE:***

if you don't want to use that then use this.

```
Bitmap cs = null;
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs);
view.draw(canvas);
canvas.save();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

If you want to share that bitmap you need to insert in Media Images like,

```
 String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), cs,
                "MyImage", null);
 Uri file = Uri.parse(path);
```

Now for sharing,

```
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
 sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                    "Share image using"));
```

Comment: And the view v1 is the dialog?

Comment: v1 is the object of View and view.getRootView(); is a view for parent layout of your dialog or Activity's parent layout.

Comment: BitmapDrawable is deprecated is it necessary to get it in a BitmapDrawable is the Bitmap not enough?

Comment: what is the worse case then, when its deprecated?

Comment: view is the old v1 and what is rel?

Comment: Sorry was typing mistake

Comment: And then I can send/share the canvas?

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Wow that is nice, the picture hasn't the best quality then but it is working.

Comment: With the BitmapFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom dialog separately using activity context and use it in a separate activity.

Comment: I have a custom dialog class, what to do then?

Comment: use this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535398/how-to-implement-a-dialog-for-different-activities